# How many ways are there to put $N$ different balls in $M$ different boxes so that no box is empty.

Tags: combinatorics

You are given $N$ different balls and $M$ different boxes. In how many ways can one distribute the balls so that no box is empty?

I've found it hard to answer, I've listed a few cases, but it seems to be much more complicated when $M$ is getting bigger. I don't know how to proceed. Any help appreciated.

Comment: If the boxes were indistinguishable, I would have thought the answer was [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)   $\lbrace{N\atop M}\rbrace$. Since they are distinguishable, you have to multiply this by $M!$, so $M! \lbrace{N\atop M}\rbrace = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{M} (-1)^{i} \binom{M}{i} (M-i)^N$

Comment: @Henry That should be an answer and OP should select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of ways with no restrictions is $N^M$. We now use inclusion exclusion. 
The number of ways to do so with at least $k$ boxes empty is ${M \choose k} \times N^{M-k}$ (the number of ways to choose the empty boxes, and the number of ways to distribute the remaining numbers).

So we obtain the answer $$\sum_{k=0}^{M-1} {M \choose k}N^{M-k} (-1)^k$$
which is simply $(N-1)^M$ by considering binomial expansion.

Comment: Thanks, I've found the answer is a special case of [Twelvefold way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way).

Comment: I do not see how this works with $N=3$ and $M=2$, where I would expect the number to be $6$

Comment: With no restrictions the number is $M^N.$ With a particular set of $k$ boxes empty and no other restriction, it's $(M-k)^N.$

Comment: This is incorrect. **Henry**’s answer is correct.

Answer (score 3):

*From comment as requested:*

If the boxes were indistinguishable, I would have thought the answer was [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) $\left\{ {N \atop M} \right\}$.

Since they are distinguishable, you have to multiply this by $M!$ so $$M! \left\{ {N \atop M} \right\} = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{M} (-1)^{i} \binom{M}{i} (M-i)^N$$