# Distributing $r$ distinct objects in $n$ distinct bins with three different conditions

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Given $r$ distinct objects to put into $n$ distinct bins,in how many this can be done if:

- Every bin can contains **at most** one object $\;\;(r\le n$)?
- Every bin contains **only** one objects$\;\;(r= n$)?
- Every bin contains **at least** one objects$\;\;(r\ge n$)?

We choose which one of the $r$ objects are going to be contained in which one of the bins,this can be done in $\binom{r}{k}\binom{n}{k}$,summing over all possible $k$'s gives:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{r}\binom{r}{k}\binom{n}{k}=\binom{r+n}{r}$$

---

The first objects has $n$ bins to be contained in,the second object has $n-1$ choices,finally the last object has $1$ choice,by the multiplication law the number of such distribution is $n!$.

---

Denote by $k_i$ the number of objects in the $i$th bin,clearly $k_1+k_2+...+k_n=r$,since every bin contains at least one objects hence we are looking for the number of nonnegative integral solutions to the equation $k_1+k_2+...+k_n=r-n$ which is $$\binom{r-n+n-1}{r-n}$$

I'm not sure if the answers are true,so it would be highly appreciated if someone check them.

Comment: I would have thought you need $r \le n$ for the first question, $r=n$ for the second, and $r\ge n$ for the third.  Your final answer seems to ignore the point that the objects are distinct.

Answer (score 1):

For the first with $r \le n$, I would have thought you have $n$ choices for the first object, $n-1$ choices for the second, ..., $n-r+1$ choices for the $r$th so overall $\dfrac{n!}{(n-r)!}$ choices

For the second with $r = n$, $n!$ choices looks correct; this is a special case of both the first and third

For the third with $r \ge n$, this looks like [an earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3247610/how-many-ways-are-there-to-put-n-different-balls-in-m-different-boxes-so-tha/) where I suggested using [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) and so $n! \left\{ {r \atop n} \right\} = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} (-1)^{i} \binom{n}{i} (n-i)^r$ choices